# Change sliders look in gimp

Tags: gimp, linux

Current look of the opacity slider

[image]

I want to change the gimp to be look like this.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, where did you come across the 2nd screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp 2.8, the sliders (like opacity) are a custom widget, not the standard GTK widget. There is no option in Gimp for changing it to the style you want.

You might be able to change it [via theming](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=10531&start=30#p144285), but creating a custom theme is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: And note that if you do this change, you lose their coarse (upper half)/fine (lower half) adjustment interaction.